# How to name the "=" of a Haskell expression?

Tags: haskell, semantics

```
let a = 3
```

Does it mean:

- "Construct an object named a" or
- "bind value 3 to object a" or
- "assign a value to variable a"?

If everything in Haskell is a function, so can I say here a is also a function? But functions can be called, how can I call "a"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can't learn the barest basics of a new language by asking about them on SO. That is what tutorials are for.

Comment: LET a BE 3. We give a value a name, this is all about it.

Comment: @dfeuer I find it a good question, and it shows that the OP wants to understand something. Your and my ideas of how to learn something may be different from how the OP approaches things. That doesn't change the fact that the question touches an important concept - referential transaprency - and we shouldn't get tired too early to explain it again and again. Just my 0,02€

Comment: I also do wonder why "everything is a function in haskell" is stated here with such confidence, when it is clearly false... but, I see a lot of people thinking this. Why is this so common? is there some resource somewhere that claims that everything in haskell is a function? Why would people even believe or think this in the first place? :|  there must be somewhere everyone is getting this from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let a=3
```

> "Construct an object named a"

No, this is not common terminology in Haskell.

> "bind value 3 to object a"

This is closer. One could simply say "bind value 3 to name (or variable, or identifier) `a`". There are no "objects" in Haskell.

> "assign a value to variable a"

No, "assignment" usually implies that one can mutate the value of a variable, when this is not the case in pure functional programming.

Personally, I'd just read `let a = 3` as "define `a` as `3`". In Haskell, most of the time, we reason about the values of variables, disregarding when exactly such values are constructed / allocated / garbage collected and how exactly the values are represented in memory. So, we usually avoid to think about "how" operationally a program is executed, focusing more on "what" is the result, and whether it is the intended one ("denotationally").

Of course, after we get the intended result, we do start caring about the performance of our programs. For that, we need to have at least a rough idea about the "how" the program is executed, its memory allocations, etc.

Comment: I think "bind to name" is definitely more approrpriate in Haskell than "bind to variable"...

Comment: @ErikAllik Possibly so. I sometimes think of a "variable" as  a "name with a scope", where a "name" is just a string/syntactic identifier. Anyway, I edited.

Answer (score 3):

First, just to get this out of the way, **not everything in Haskell is a function**. Functions are actually their very own type denoted by the `(->)` operator. This is way the type declarations for functions tend to look like `func :: a -> b`. Most things in Haskell are, however, lazy, meaning that values are not evaluated until they are actually needed. This is similar to how argumentless functions act in other languages, so values can, for some purposes at least, be *conceptualized* as functions. That does not mean, though, that the `a` in your example is callable.

As for the phrasing, either of the latter two are accurate. I prefer the second, but both work. In Haskell, `let a = 3` doesn't really *construct* an argument, so the first doesn't make a lot of sense. (not at the level that most Haskell programmers work anyway; I don't know how the generated machine code works under the covers).

All in all, I advise you go take some introductory courses on Haskell. Most of them cover this sort of stuff.

EDIT: As some other answers have pointed out, the word "assign" tends to imply some level of mutability, which Haskell does not have. For that reason, I would advise against the last phrasing.

Comment: Haskell doesn't generally have anything I would call "bytecode".

Comment: @SebastianRedl, yes, I couldn't think of a better word at the time. I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean:
>
> "Construct an object named a" or "bind value 3 to object a" or "assign
>   a value to variable a"?

No, no, and again, no.

First, in Haskell we speak of **values**, not objects. Numbers, for example, are values, and you know that every number has infinitely many names. For example:

```
0
the predecessor of 1
the predecessor of the precdecessor of 2
the predecessor of ...(32493 times)... the predecessor of 32495
the product of 1 and 0
the product of the successor of 1 and 0
...
... and so on, you get the idea
...
```

Now, as in normal language, when we need to mention something with a complicated name very often, we tend to invent a short name. For example, when we write an article about activities of the "bureau for the promotion of alcohol, tobacco and firearms" we introduce an abbreviation like in

> The bureau for the promotion of alcohol, tobacco and firearms (ATF) is
>   agian in the news. The chief of the ATF, Drink A'Glass, said in an
>   interview that beer alone is no good when you can't have a good smoke
>   at the same time. ...

Likewise, in Haskell, we may need to mention "the square of the first element of the tuple that is the result of applying function f to some list whose name is *xs*" and we can give it a name like so

```
let a = sqr . fst . f $ xs
```

and henceforth we can just use `a`.
Because of *referential transparency* it doesn't matter for the meaning of the program if you do this and use the name `a` or write the complicated expression all the time. Thus, this principle guarantees that the meaning of the name and of its definition is the same in the same way that "the predecessor of 2" and "the successor of 0" are the same as 1.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, variable does not mean that things are mutable but that there value are not fixed and depend on the context. For example, when you define the mathematical funcion `f(x) : x -> x+1`, `x` is variable in the way it depends on what you pass to `f` when you call it, where as `f` will be always the same function. There is no notion of mutability but only of scope. In Haskell I suppose things are the same, a variable is any 'binding' which is not global but lives in a limited scope. I would use `defines` but I don't see why 'assign' wouldn't be appropriate.